# OSerrorが発生するようになった

Tags: python, windows, spyder

Python spyder についてどなたかご教授お願い致します。

spyderにて以下のコードを記載し Run を押したところ、画像のようなエラーが発生しました。

**コード**

```
from pylinac import Starshot
Starshot.run_demo()
```

**コード**

```
raise OSError(err)

OSError: -2

tempfile.tif: Cannot read TIFF header.
```

以前に同様のことをした際は発生しなかったのですが、その解決方法がわからず困っています。
このエラーはどういったもので、どのように解決すべきでしょうか？

その間にしたことといえばWdirの変更や初期設定へ戻すボタンを押しましたが、
それらも関係しているのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ**
[image]

Comment: エラーメッセージだけではなく、実際のコードも質問中に含めてみてください。また、ソースコードやエラーメッセージは **文字のまま** 貼り付けてもらうと読み手にとってより親切かと思います。 / 質問はいつでも [edit] できます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問を修正いたしました。

Comment: SpyderやAnacondaではない素のPython3.8.5で新たにpylinacをインストールすると問題無く動作しました。必要なライブラリ/モジュールが古いか不足しているのでは？ AnacondaやSpyderも含めて全部アップデートしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。一度、アップデートして確認させていただきます。

Comment: やはり、アップデート、再インストールしても同様のエラーが発生します。Macも所有しているのでPylinacをインストールして試してみたところ実行できました。なにかしら設定やコードが誤っている可能性があるようなのですが、同じ経験をした方や解決方法をご存じな方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 環境で起こりやすいエラーだったようです。

[python PIL Pillow: save image suddenly does not work - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877504/python-pil-pillow-save-image-suddenly-does)

上記リンク先の [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59879455) を参考に pillow を異なる方法でダウンロードしました。
`pip install Pillow`ではなく、`python -m pip install Pillow` とコマンドを入力しました。

ご協力ありがとうございました。